# Tomcat 5.5 where is the connection string of my application?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, datasource

In the web.inf of an application I have

```
<resource-ref>
    <description></description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
     <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

I would like to know where jdbc/myDS points.
I checked in Tomcat 5.5\conf\server.xml but I don't see any references to it.
Where could I find the connection string of jdbc/myDS ?

Comment: Probably in your webapp's context.xml file.

Comment: In my webapp I don't have any context.xml file